# Visual Studio go to where triggers 'Debug assertion failed'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When debugging a C++ application with Visual Studio, I got a sudden error "Debug Assertion Failed". Can I go the the line or function that triggers that error?

Comment: The message box should have 3 buttons, Abort, Retry, and Ignore. Last sentence of the text should be (Press Retry to debug the application). So, just press Retry.

Comment: @Dialecticus cool. I can see which function that initiates the error.

Answer (score 0):

click `Retry` button to start the debug session